# Will a CD automatically get infected when it is inserted?

Tags: virus

If my computer has virus and I inserted a CD, will the virus automatically move there?

Comment: is the CD writable?

Comment: Store bought CD's are close and no further data can be written to them.  Since the development of USB sticks the use CD-R and even DVD writable are quickly fading into the history books.  Since the number of users is small hackers don't have as much motive to go through the effort.  Even though there is nothing stopping them except the time commitment to develop and test it.  Also it makes the virus payload larger for marginal gains.  A hacker can only write to cd-rw or disc that hasn't had its session closed.

Answer (score 7):

If it is a CD-ROM (i.e. read-only) the virus cannot move there since the medium is not writable in the first place. This cannot be bypassed - it is a physical limitation not a software limitation.

If it is a CD-RW (writable) and the drive is capable to write CD-RW (most do today) the virus  can still not move there directly: a CD-RW does not behave like an external hard disk or USB drive where one can simply write a file on it. Instead a disk image needs to be prepared and then written to the drive which usually needs special programs. Of course, a virus might have this capabilities by itself or is able to make use of such programs found on the system. But it is unlikely that the virus has such capabilities unless it is explicitly designed for this use case (i.e. usually not).